# How to get a flex-item in my navigation to align to the right, next to my hamburger?

Tags: html, css

Pasting my staging site here: http://staging-netpayadvance.kinsta.cloud/

I am having trouble aligning my login and apply buttons to the right side, next to my hamburger. It's staying left-aligned with my logo.

I tried using `justify-content: flex-end` but it doesn't seem like that works. I am not too familiar with flexbox but I'm assuming it has something to do with me using `flex-direction: row-reverse` on the nav?

Answer (score 1):

On your `div.content` in the navigation add `flex-grow: 1`;

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px)
header .wrapper nav > .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This will make the `div.content` take as much space as possible, growing, and with your current css it aligns itself right next to the hamburger icon